# "Limit selection to visible" Toggle NOT working with Weight Painting

Tags: weight-painting

I recently was attempting to weight paint a project I've been working on for a while, and I realized that while I was weight painting it, the "Limit Selection to Visible" toggle which would usually either limit my weight paint to geometry I can see or not was not actually working. I tried testing this in a new blend file and got the same result.

I recently switched over to a new computer and redownloaded both Blender 2.79 and CATS blender plugin, so I'm wondering if maybe there was some user preference that I forgot to toggle on when my settings and preferences weren't transferred over?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Clean reinstall of Blender seems to have fixed the issue. Not sure what caused it in the first place.